# Google Earth Engine Dividing an ImageCollection by a constant

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, evi

I'm using GEE to calculate the EVI of Sentinel-2 images in a specific area. To do this, I need to divide the Sentinel-2 images for scaling purposes. I'd like to use ee.ImageCollection.map, but as a newcomer to GEE, I keep running into errors.
My current code is:

```
//get list of sentinel data with less than 50% cloud coverage
var sentinel2016datasetraw = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterBounds(studyarea)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50))
                  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
                  print('List of Sentinel2 Dataset:', sentinel2016datasetraw);

//function to divide
var divide10000 = function(image) {
  return image.expression('sentinel2016datasetraw/10000');
};

//mapping
print(sentinel2016datasetraw.map(divide10000));
```

When I run this, I get the error

> Image.parseExpression: Expression contains undeclared variables: [sentinel2016datasetraw].

How do I make this code properly divide my images by 10000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function instead:

```
var divide10000 = function(image) {
  return image.divide(10000);
};
```